# Remove LI from UL

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to delete / remove a image from my image list. I'm too tired think straight, so I need some assistance please.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li id="listItem_dsc_6436.jpg"> 
  <a href="http://storelocator.com/wp-content/uploads/slgallery/brand/5f/c6/dsc_6436.jpg"><img alt="dsc_6436.jpg" src="http://storelocator.com/wp-content/uploads/slgallery/brand/5f/c6/thumb/dsc_6436.jpg"/></a>
  <div class="buttonPanel">
    <span title="Delete image" class="btnRemoveItem floatRight" id="dsc_6436.jpg"> </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').click(function(){
  jQuery('#listItem_' +jQuery(this).attr('id')).remove();
});
```

This is not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$(this).closest('li').remove()`.
You could also add a class (eg, `ImageItem`) to the `li`, then call `closest('li.ImageItem').remove()`.

The [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest#expr) function finds the nearest parent element that matches a selector.

**EDIT**:
To make it fade out, write the following:

```
var li = $(this).closest('li')
li.fadeOut('slow', function() { li.remove(); });
```

This will remove the element once the animation is completed.

Comment: Great, that worked. Is there a way I can apply fadeOut() to his?

Comment: Ah, found the answer: `jQuery(this).closest('li').fadeOut(400, function() { $(this).remove(); });`

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be the `.` in the selector that's confusing it. You're telling it to find the thing with the ID of `listItem_dsc_6436` and a class of `jpg`, which isn't exactly what you want :-)

If you can, replace the `.` serverside. Or you could even do it clientside with some jQuery fu. Otherwise, SLaks suggestion should work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

IE dislikes clickable spans. Especially empty ones. Enter some text into it.

[Some more versions here](http://doctype.com/span-link-clickable-ie-surprise)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't like dots in ids:
[docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)
Remove '.' from id and everything will work fine ;)